# Xamarin Forms Android showing Tabbed Page inside Master Details Page is showing blank empty screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, master-detail, tabbedpage

In my `Xamarin Forms` application I am having `Tabbed Page` as first `Detail page` of `Master Details Page`. So, while running my `Droid` application it is showing `empty` blank screen for few seconds and after that it is showing the correct `Tabbed Page`. However, if I run the same project in `iOS` it is not showing any `Empty` or `blank` screen; Tabbed page is rendering fast.

**What I have tried**

If I set any other normal `Content Page` as first `Detail page` instead of `Tabbed Page` means  that page is rendering fast in `Droid`

and also I have tried after updating the `Xamarin.Forms` from **v2.5.1.444934** to **v3.1.0.697729** but no luck.

So, I confirmed that the `Empty or Blank` screen is showing in `Droid App` for few seconds because of `Tabbed Page`. Is there any work around to resolve the problem. Thanks in advance.

**Login.cs**

```
MasterDetailPage masterDetail =  new MasterDetail();
masterDetail.IsPresented = false;
Application.Current.MainPage = masterDetail;
```

using the above code in `Login.cs` after successful of Login API

**MasterDetail.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"            
                  x:Class="Test.MasterDetail" IsPresented="false">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage"/>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

**MasterDetail.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MasterDetail : MasterDetailPage
  {  
   
    public MasterDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
        
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new BottomTabbedPage());         
    }
  }
```

**BottomTabbedPage.xaml.cs**

```
public class BottomTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
    public BottomTabbedPage()
    {          
            //setting false to hide navigation bar
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
          
            Children.Clear();              
           
            var map = new NavigationPage(new ConsumerMap());
            map.Icon = "map_icon";
            map.Title = ""Home;         
            Children.Add(map);  

            var order = new NavigationPage(new Order());
            order.Icon = "order_icon";
            order.Title = ""Order;         
            Children.Add(order);           

            var history = new NavigationPage(new History());
            history.Icon = "history_icon";
            history.Title = "History";         
            Children.Add(history);
     }              
       
}
```

**BottomTabbedPage.xaml.cs**

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"          
            x:Class="Test.BottomTabbedPage">
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Show some code please?

Comment: @G.hakim I have updated the code please check and let me know if you need any further information

Comment: Are you loading any data from any those 3 pages ? 
When you load tabbed page it will load all pages inside the tabbed page. If you are loading the data then move those inside when view appear.

Comment: Your Master Detail page is not properly implemented take a look at my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169049/hamburger-menu-xamarin-forms/49175351#49175351 and then implement your tabbed page into this

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?