# How to design MasterPage from TabbedPage in Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have problem to design `MasterDetailPage` drawer from `TabbedPage` in xamarin forms.
Here I will show image:
[image: Tabbed Page instead of Master Page]

Please give me some help on this. Thanks.

I am Using Bottom Tabbed Page render
Tabbed Page Code

https://github.com/NAXAM/bottomtabbedpage-xamarin-forms

The above link, i will implement the bottom tabbed page

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: So basically you want tabbed page embedded in a master-detail right? If yes check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49175351/7462031 and where I am assigning the detail page assign your page there

Comment: No, i don't want any tabbed page embedded in a master. I have a problem in designing a master page which is coming from a Tabbed page.

Comment: I am Not getting any reply , from last 15 hrs

Comment: Well why don't you show me your code and we can see what i can do

Comment: sorry, I will change the question again and i put one example link also... please once see the question

Comment: please tell solution, as soon as possible

Comment: I am not getting any reply from last 2 days.. please give me the reply