# white screen while navigating to Master-Detail page

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, master-detail

I am working on xamarin forms application.I my app first page is login after successful login I'm changing master detail page as mainpage like

```
    App.Current.MainPage = new MasterDetailPage();
```

while navigating to MasterDetailpage it is Showing white blank page.Can any one help me how to remove the white blank page.

Comment: If your page has base class `MasterDetailPage` like `public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage` then you should do as `Detail = new NavigationPage(new Page1());`

Comment: Check my answer here to understand how to use a [hamburger menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49175351/7462031)

Comment: Did you create MasterDetailPage correctly ？

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Experiencing the same issue.