# xamarin master-detail page CS0102 nand CS0229

Tags: c#, xamarin, master-detail

I am learning Xamarin at the moment and I need to implement master-detail page for an app. I found the official instructions online, downloaded sample code, and it has 2 folders: 1 with CS, another with XAML. After trying to replace those folders with ContentPage only, I get 2 ambiguity errors which confuses me. The question is: is it possible to do what I am trying to do, and what could I do? Thanks in advance.
P.S. Link of the Master-Detail page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page

[This is the error I'm getting and how I am trying to make it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beONY.png)

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```css
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage // added partial. What is partial anyway?
    {
        MasterPage masterPage; //what's dis

        public MainPage()
        {
            var masterPage = new MasterPage(); // added var
            //Master = masterPage;
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContactsPage());

            masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
            {
                MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;
            }
        }

        void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
            if (item != null)
            {
                Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
                masterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
                IsPresented = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MasterPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ListView ListView { get { return listView; } }

        ListView listView;

        public MasterPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var masterPageItems = new List<MasterPageItem>();
            masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "Contacts",
                IconSource = "contacts.png",
                TargetType = typeof(ContactsPage)
            });
            masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "TodoList",
                IconSource = "todo.png",
                TargetType = typeof(TodoListPage)
            });
            masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "Reminders",
                IconSource = "reminders.png",
                TargetType = typeof(ReminderPage)
            });

            listView = new ListView
            {
                ItemsSource = masterPageItems,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    var grid = new Grid { Padding = new Thickness(5, 10) };
                    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(30) });
                    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Star });

                    var image = new Image();
                    image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "IconSource");
                    var label = new Label { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
                    label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");

                    grid.Children.Add(image);
                    grid.Children.Add(label, 1, 0);

                    return new ViewCell { View = grid };
                }),
                SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None
            };

            Icon = "hamburger.png";
            Title = "Personal Organiser";
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 40, 0, 0);
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = { listView }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetailPageNavigation;assembly=MasterDetailPageNavigation"
      x:Class="MasterDetailPageNavigation.MainPage">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
   <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
 <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
  <NavigationPage>
   <x:Arguments>
    <local:ContactsPage />
   </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>
 </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

MasterPage.xaml:

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="using:MasterDetailPageNavigation"
    x:Class="MyApp.MasterPage"
    Padding="0,40,0,0"
    Icon="hamburger.png"
    Title="Personal Organiser">
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" x:FieldModifier="public">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:MasterPageItem}">
                    <local:MasterPageItem Title="Contacts" IconSource="contacts.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:ContactsPage}" />
                    <local:MasterPageItem Title="TodoList" IconSource="todo.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:TodoListPage}" />
                    <local:MasterPageItem Title="Reminders" IconSource="reminders.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:ReminderPage}" />
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="5,10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

App.xaml.cs

```css
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            MainPage = new MyApp.MainPage();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Had to upload it as a CSS snippet, as code sample doesn't go really well. I hope it is ok. MasterPage should contain Links to ContacstsPage, ReminderPage and ToDoListPage. I can upload it, if necessary.

P.S. GitHub source. Maybe it'll help: https://github.com/EdgarKa/MasterDetailPage

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that we expect questions to be searchable, so that other users who face the same problem as you can search for and find your post. To that end, please include the error and your code as text in the question, rather than as an image.

Comment: presumably you have "masterPage" defined in both your XAML and code behind.  It's impossible to say, though, without seeing your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hamburger Menu Xamarin Forms (MasterDetailPage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169049/hamburger-menu-xamarin-forms-masterdetailpage)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I've changed my Title and added the code. If you need anything else, I'll upload it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

You are already declared `masterPage` variable in xaml file:

```
<local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
```

After that, you can use this variable in cs file without new declaration, like this:

```
public MainPage()
{
    masterPage = new MasterPage(); // already declared in xaml

    Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContactsPage());

    masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. I can leave my project, maybe it will help :/   https://github.com/EdgarKa/MasterDetailPage

Answer (score 0):

Solved, had to remove ListView listView; (line 10 in MasterPage.xaml.cs)