# Navigating from MasterPage does not show back button

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using prism and it's not a Prism problem but I guess how forms works.

I have a master page and when I navigate to another page from the navigation menu It should show the back button on the title bar but it doesnt.

My code from the mainPage.xaml

```
      <MasterDetailPage.Master>
         <views:MenuPage/>
      </MasterDetailPage.Master>
      <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
          <ContentPage 
             BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
      </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Code behind

```
 public partial class MainPage : IMasterDetailPageOptions, INavigatingAware
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool IsPresentedAfterNavigation { get; } = Device.Idiom != TargetIdiom.Phone;

    public void OnNavigatingTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        (Master as INavigatingAware)?.OnNavigatingTo(parameters);
        (Master?.BindingContext as INavigatingAware)?.OnNavigatingTo(parameters);
    }
}
```

What do I need todo to make the back button show when navigating to a page from master detail?

Many thanks

Comment: The code you provide is not enough to reproduce your problem. So can you provide a sample so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: You might want to refer to this I guess : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169049/hamburger-menu-xamarin-forms-masterdetailpage