# Why the "Hamburger" is not showing? I want to be able to access the Menu page by clicking on the hamburger icon

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This is the code I have written to create the Master Detail Page:
Please check it out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="DemoApp.MenuPage" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DemoApp.Views" MasterBehavior="Default">
       <MasterDetailPage.Master>
          <ContentPage Title="MenuPage" Icon="menuIcon.png" Padding="0,50,0,0">
             <ContentPage.Content>
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
                   <Button Text="Home" />
                   <Button Text="Login" />
                   <Button Text="Logout" />
                   <Button Text="Exit" />
                </StackLayout>
             </ContentPage.Content>
          </ContentPage>
       </MasterDetailPage.Master>
       <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
          <local:Login/>
       </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    </MasterDetailPage>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hamburger Menu Xamarin Forms (MasterDetailPage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169049/hamburger-menu-xamarin-forms-masterdetailpage)

Answer (score 2):

From Xamarin 4.0, this `MasterDetailPage` feature can implemented much easier using `Shell`. David has made a video on showing how to use `Shell`. His [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0y1bUAcOjZY)

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code in a plain project and no errors so far, to check further the Detail page code would be needed. I mean the content of

```
   <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
      <local:Login/>
   </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Comment: I have found the issue. The hamburger icon wasn't showing because I didn't put the <local:Login/> inside a <NavigationPage> block. The issue was fixed after adding: 

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>

        <NavigationPage>

            <x:Arguments>

                <local:Login/>

            </x:Arguments>

        </NavigationPage>        

    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>