# Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin project I am using masterDetailPage and replacing the detail section with a new ContentPage. I think Android's hardware back button is have the problem knowing you are on a different page. I tried adding base.OnBackPressed in the MainActivity but that didn't fix it. When using the app on Android and Navigate to a new page the back button should send you back to the original page the current app will minimize the program.
Is there anyway to do this?

```cs
var masterDetailPage = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
masterDetailPage.Detail = new BaseNavigationPage((new SearchPage()));
```

MainActivity

```cs
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    base.OnBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hamburger Menu Xamarin Forms (MasterDetailPage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169049/hamburger-menu-xamarin-forms-masterdetailpage)

Comment: This is about the Andriod's hardware back button

Comment: you want to navigate back to previously loaded detail page even though the navigation stack count is 1?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things :

- In android OnBackPressed() , return false if it is master detail page: this will stop application from closing.
- Have your own stack for keeping track of all the navigations on MasterDetailPage

```
Stack<ContentPage> myStack = new Stack<ContentPage> ();

var masterDetailPage = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
var naviPage = new BaseNavigationPage ((new SearchPage ()));
masterDetailPage.Detail = naviPage;
myStack.Push (naviPage);

//in Master detail page
public override void OnBackPressed () {
    if (myStack.Count > 1) {
        var lastPageLoaded = myStack.Pop ();
        this.Detail = new BaseNavigationPage (lastPageLoaded);
    }
}
```

I wouldnt suggest making the app always go back to previously loaded page, supppose if the user opens same detail page like 100 times then clicking back would be same page. If thats required push only of the current page is different than last page.