# Is there a way to automatically change the selected menu page in a master detail project when the detail changes?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

**Background:**

My project uses the "Master Detail" project from Xamarin.Forms, so it comes equipped with the hamburger menu button in the top left which is supposed to be the main source of navigation throughout the app. However, my app requires the user to go through multiple of those screens without the use of the hamburger menu. But when a user uses my own buttons to change the detail, the hamburger menu still says the user is on the previous page.

For example, a user is on Page A. They click a button outside of the menu which sends them to Page B. The menu will still show Page A.

**My Attempt:**

I really didn't know where to start, so I tried taking the MenuItemType and passing it through the following function:

```cs
// This changes the screen without changing the menu and it works.
((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Detail = new NavigationPage(new PageB());

// This was my attempt to change the menu.
(Application.Current.MainPage as MenuPage).RootPage.NavigateFromMenu((id)MenuItemType.PageB);
```

But that returned a Null Reference Exception when run.

I've also tried manually calling the list view associated with the hamburger menu and changing the selectedItem property, but that didn't work either. Is there any way to change the selected menu?

**For Clarity:**

Since StackOverflow won't let me post a video, [here's a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VgypiZKPbTV8YXSSbyyyEb8jxDFBP78G/view?usp=sharing) to how the app acts. As you can see, I use the Menu to go to the "About" Page. I click a button on the screen which takes me back to the "Browse" Page. However, when I open the menu, it still says "About" is selected.  I can't reselect "About" until the menu moves away, meaning I have to reopen "Browse" despite already being on that screen.

What I'm looking for is a function which will automatically change the selected menu item to "Browse" when I press that button on the "About" Page. The app is currently using a Master Detail Page which has the "Detail" component changing from the About Page to the Browse Page. The menu page is a Content Page which came built with the app beforehand.

Comment: What do you mean the menu will still show page A? Question ain't clear enough...

Comment: It's not so clear about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I added a video and tried to make a clearer description for the task at hand. @G.hakim

Comment: Actually, you have not created your Hamburger Menu correctly, you seem to be loading two different MasterDetailPages what you should rather do is something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49175351/7462031