# MasterDetailPage - can't find any way to target 'detail' page window

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created a Master Detail Page

I am loading a list of items into the 'detail' frame / window

I want to replace the contents of that page with a template / view which never has any reason to exist as an item in the Menu Items

I have tried replacing MainPage and Navigation which load the page but you lose the Master Detail context - the menu

Please can someone tell me what I call in order to replace the current page with one of my choice while staying within the context of Master Detail?

This does not work, for example - it removes the MasterDetail menu

```
 Navigation.PushAsync(new Arcade.Index());
```

I have created the MasterDetailPage by pretty much letting Visual Studio generate it. I set it after a successful login, like so:

```
            var welcome = new Pages.Welcome();


            Application.Current.MainPage = welcome;
```

This is an excerpt of the XAML for Welcome

```
 <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <pages:WelcomeMaster x:Name="MasterPage" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
 <NavigationPage>
    <x:Arguments>
    <pages:Index />
   </x:Arguments>
 </NavigationPage>
```

I've added this to the code behind for Welcome

```
        InitializeComponent();
        MasterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;

        this.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Arcade.Index());
```

In spite of all that, when I call this later, the MasterDetail menu disappears

```
    ((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Detail = new Arcade.Index();
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: set the Detail property of the MasterDetailPage

Comment: I've read that a few times but there is no way of accessing that from the view I've loaded. There is no relationship between the page I've loaded to the Master Detail that I can find

Comment: either use Navigation to navigate to a new page within the Detail frame, OR reference the current MasterDetail from the App.Current.MainPage, OR just manually pass a reference to your MasterDetail when you create the detail page

Comment: App.Current.MainPage replaces the entire window, I cannot see any way of accessing the existing MasterDetail via that method. Navigation I gave in my example, that replaces the entire window. I don't understand the third method?

Comment: You can check my answer out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49175351/7462031) where you can find everything related to the MasterDetail setup

Answer (score 1):

In you App.xaml.cs add static method then you can use it to navigate in you code

```
    public static void SetDatailPage(Page page)
    {
        if (App.Current.MainPage is MasterDetailPage)
        {
            var masterPage = (MasterDetailPage)App.Current.MainPage;
            masterPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
        }
    }
```

And use it like this

```
App.SetDatailPage(new YourPageYouWannaNavigateTo());
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - use `App.Current.Mainpage`

```
var md = (MasterDetailPage)App.Current.MainPage;
md.Detail = new MyPage();
```

2 - use navigation

when you initially create your detail, wrap it in a `NavigationPage`

```
this.Detail = new NavigaitionPage(new Page1());
```

then later, `Page1` can navigate to `Page2` within the `Detail` pane

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
```

3 - explicitly pass a reference to the `MasterDetailPage`

```
// when you create Page1, pass a reference to the MasterDetailPage
// you will also need to modify Page1's constructor
this.Detail = new Page1(this);
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response but I appear to be missing something fundamental. For example, this variant of what you've put above still replaces the entire window with the page I want to load - so I lose the menu. None of these options lets me load a page that keeps the MasterDetail menu. ((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Detail = (new Arcade.Index());

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong.  If you set MainPage to be a MasterDetailPage, and then you later update the **Detail** property, that will only replace the Detail, not the Master.

Comment: you may be losing the toolbar button that triggers the master page appearance (on a phone) - is that the case?

Comment: Jason, again thank you for all your help but I've gone back and edited my post above to show you more of my code in the hope you can spot something

Comment: are you testing on a phone or a tablet?

Comment: Using Android emulator for phone

Comment: how do you **know** that the Master disappears?  How do you normally toggle it?  A gesture, a toolbar button, or what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198608/discussion-between-journeyman1234-and-jason).

Comment: Jason has answered the question - it wasn't obvious to me the master was still there, but the Hamburger disappears (you can still swipe). doh.