# How can I set up master-detail with existing ContentPages (Xamarin.Forms)?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to set up Master-Detail pages in my Xamarin.Forms app to use as a Hamburger sidebar-style navigation menu.

My app is for data entry, and flows in a linear order like this:

Login Page -> Page 1 -> Page 2 -> Page 3 -> Page 4 -> Page 5

I want to use Master-Detail to have a slide-out sidebar menu so you can jump from any numbered page to any other one (e.g. you can be on page 3 and go to page 1, or page 5, etc.) The numbered pages (ContentPages) are already set up with database connections and styling, so how do I implement them into a Master-Detail relationship without creating all new pages and copy-pasting the code across?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a Login page which needs to be out of the `MasterDetailPage I would suggest you first push it into the Stack something like:

```
MainPage= new LoginPage(); //Constructor App.xaml
```

Once you do this follow my answer here and you should be good to go.

[Hamburger Menu Xamarin Forms (MasterDetailPage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169049/hamburger-menu-xamarin-forms-masterdetailpage/49175351#49175351)