# Xamarin iOS background on menu for MasterDetailPage not following PageBackgroundColour

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The background for my Xamarin iOS content page for the MasterDetailPage Master page is White and some of the menu is following this colour but the rest around it is following the dark/light theme mode for the device. Example below.

Is there a way to force this to conform to the rest of the apps styling?

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzD60.png)

Another issue you can see in the screenshot is that the menu icon isn't being used and the name of the page is being used instead if this can be resolved aswell?

MasterDetailPage below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Expenses.Views.MasterViews.Main"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Expenses.Views.MasterViews"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Expenses.Views;assembly=Expenses"
             xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Expenses.Common;assembly=Expenses"
             BackgroundColor="{x:Static common:ColorResources.PageBackgroundColor}">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
      <NavigationPage IconImageSource="hamburger.png">
          <x:Arguments>
                <pages:MainMaster x:Name="MasterPage" />
          </x:Arguments>
      </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
        <views:MyClaims />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

and Master Page below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Expenses.Common;assembly=Expenses"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Expenses.Views.MasterViews.MainMaster"
             IconImageSource="hamburger.png"
             Title = "Home"
             Appearing="MainMasterAppearing"
             BackgroundColor="{x:Static common:ColorResources.PageBackgroundColor}">
  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView x:Name="MenuItemsListView"
              SeparatorVisibility="None"
              HasUnevenRows="true"
              ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <ListView.Header>
                <StackLayout Padding="15,10" BackgroundColor="{x:Static common:ColorResources.NavBarBackgroundColor}" Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <Label
                        x:Name="EmployeeNameLabel"
                        Style="{DynamicResource SubtitleStyle}"
                        TextColor="{x:Static common:ColorResources.LabelDefaultColor}"/>
                    <Label
                        x:Name="JobTitleLabel"
                        Style="{DynamicResource SubtitleStyle}"
                        TextColor="{x:Static common:ColorResources.LabelDefaultColor}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Padding="15,10" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="20"/>
                <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                    Text="{Binding Title}" 
                    FontSize="24"
                    TextColor="{x:Static common:ColorResources.LabelDefaultColor}"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You might wanna add the code for your `MasterDetailPage!`

Comment: @FreakyAli I've updated it with the code now

Comment: What is the colour of `PageBackgroundColor` property?

Comment: Just ```Color.White```

Comment: When you directly assign the white colour to the background does it work?

Comment: No I'm afraid not

Comment: maybe you should implement a proper master-detail setup because from what I see there are no issues or maybe I do not see it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49169049/hamburger-menu-xamarin-forms-masterdetailpage

Comment: It is setup correctly in the code behind, everything is working correctly just the styling causing issues. You only notice it as an issue when you enable Dark theme

Answer (score 0):

Setting a background colour on the `ListView` resolved the issue, appears the body of the page was following the background colour but the uncoloured `ListView` was then conforming to iOS themeing